# ASP.net Identity custom user model not being used by roles, claims and login table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I am using a custom user model like so:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
 {
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    ...
 }
```

The rest of the tables created by the Identity system are a bit out of sync. A new column is created called ApplicationUser_Id which is set at the foreign key but there is still a UserId which is used a composite primary key.

[image: Generated tables]

Configuration for ApplicationUser model is

```
public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        this.Property(u => u.Firstname).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        this.Property(u => u.Lastname).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}
```

How do I tell EF to continue using UserId as the foreign key and get rid of ApplicationUser_Id?

Thanks

UPDATE:
 Working as expected until I add custom configuration for ApplicationUser.

DataContext.cs

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
```

ApplicationUserConfiguration.cs

```
public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        this.Property(u => u.Firstname).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        this.Property(u => u.Lastname).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: in ApplicationUser  did you override the ID property ?

Comment: No I am not overriding UserId, I am happy with it being String.

Comment: can't you use `Key` and `ForeignKey` attributes on your models?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh No I don't want to convolute my entity with business rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did reproduce the issue then i fixed it by adding modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
 before
 base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 
so the function now

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
```

Comment: I am calling base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); in my context.

Comment: i did reproduce the issue then i fixed it by adding             modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
before             base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); so the function now    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);



        }

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding conventions, so you need to manually map your table.
Something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserClaims>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.UserId) 
    .WithOptional(t => t.Claims);
```

Comment: I have already tried this modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().HasRequired(t => t.UserId) and it doesnt work. I can't seem to find AspNetUserClaims.

Comment: Try IdentityUserClaim

Comment: Thats what I had modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().HasRequired(t => t.UserId); The navigation property 'UserId' is not a declared property on type 'IdentityUserClaim'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.